# Assigns usage in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to ask why i'm always getting nil value when running rspec controller test ?
I already read in this site and most of answers because plurals word using inside assigns
but in my case thats not working and i still got the same value
This is my Controller

```
  class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :find_contact, only: [:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]

  def index
    authorize! :index, Contact
    @contact = Contact.accessible_by(current_ability)
    # @contact = Contact.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @contact = current_user.contact.new(contact_params)

    if @contact.save
      redirect_to @contact
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end

  def update
    # @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    if @contact.update(contact_params)
      redirect_to @contact
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

  end

  def destroy
    @contact.destroy

    redirect_to contacts_path
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname,
                                    :lastname,
                                    :alamat,
                                    details_attributes: [:id, :number, :_destroy])
  end

  def find_contact
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And this is my simple controller test

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ContactsController do

  describe "Contact"  do 

    it "succesfully create the contact" do
      contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact)
      get :index
      # byebug
      expect(assigns(:contacts)).to eq([contact])
    end

  end

end
```

Even i change `assigns(:contacts)` to `assigns(:contact)` i still got the same value. So where is that i am do wrong ?
Please kindly answer this, big thanks

Comment: Specify the Rails version you're using please.

Comment: Rails 5.1.4 sir

Comment: You have `@contact` variable in index method of your controller while you're looking for(or checking if it assigns) `@contacts` instead in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

> Even i change `assigns(:contacts)` to `assigns(:contact)` i still got the
>   same value. So where is that i am do wrong ?

`assigns` and `assert_template` have been remove and extracted to a [gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing) in Rails 5.

[`Source`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1393)

Answer (score 0):

You have an authorization check

```
authorize! :index, Contact
```

before the assignment to `@contact`.

But your test has no setup in order to grant permissions to the requesting user in any way.

It probably makes sense to have an additional test alongside the one you show in order to spot errors like this. E.g:

```
it "returns 200 (OK)" do
  get :index
  expect(response.response_code).to eq(200)
end
```